# How do I add a custom function in an excel scatterplot?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel files. Each file contains a scatterplot with a trendline. I am looking to copy the trendline from one of the scatterplots and paste it onto the other scatterplot. Meaning, the latter scatterplot would have both trendlines.

How would I do this? I am thinking of somehow adding a custom function into the latter scatterplot and pasting the former scatterplot's trendline equation. But I am not sure how I could do this.

Is there a way I could add a custom function/trendline into a scatterplot graph in excel?

Answer (score 0):

Excel calculates the trend line from the underlying data. It is not possible to copy just a trend line from one chart to another. Conceptually, you can do this:

Chart A and Chart B both have data and trend lines.

- add the data from Chart B to Chart A as a new series
- add a trend line for the new data series
- format the series to have no lines and no markers, so it is invisible and just the trend line remains

This can be automated with VBA code.

The concept of "adding a custom function into a chart" does not exist. VBA code is stored in VBA modules and can manipulate charts and other aspects of the workbook.